# Checking FileAttributes enumeration

Tags: c#

New to C# and I don't really understand how the below code is determining if the file is read-only or not.  In particular, how does the (attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) evaluate to something that does or doesn't == FileAttributes.ReadOnly.

I'm guessing the & is doing some sort of bitwise AND??  I just don't follow how this works.  Can anyone provide an explanation?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes("c:/Temp/testfile.txt");
            if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("read-only file");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not read-only file");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly` is a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).  This means that it will return the value of `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` if the appropriate bit is set in `attributes`, otherwise it will return 0.

> A bitwise AND takes two binary representations of equal length and performs the logical AND operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 and the second bit is 1; otherwise, the result is 0.

The reason for this, is because a file can have many [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) set.  For example, it can be a `Hidden` (value 2), `ReadOnly` (value 1), `System` (value 4) file.  The attributes for that file would be the bitwise OR of all of those attributes.  The value of the file's attribute would be 1+2+4 = 7.

Performing a simple equality check, e.g.

```
if ( attributes == FileAttributes.ReadOnly )
```

would return false, because the `7 != 1`.  But the bitwise AND, does show the read only bit is set.  In binary this looks like:

```
Attributes: 0111
ReadOnly  : 0001
AND       : 0001
```

---

As has been pointed out by @cadrell0, the `enum` type can take care of this for you using the [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method.  The check for the readonly flag becomes much simpler, and looks like

```
if ( attributes.HasFlag( FileAttributes.ReadOnly ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine("read-only file");
```

Comment: Don't forget the [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method.  I'm sure it does the same thing internally, but I think it is clearer than bitwise operations.